# Magento Mini cart not updated based on Bulk product add

Tags: magento-1.7

I switched off redirecting to shopping cart when adding a product to it. After I did that, I noticed something strange: The mini-cart in the sidebar doesn’t show any prices when I added the products to the cart. It will say: “Product name, 1 x €0.00”. The total amount does show up, and is correct too. I can keep adding products, and all will say €0.00, until I visit the shopping cart. Once I did, and I go back to the other pages, the prices do show up in the mini-cart.

Does anyone have any idea what could be causing this?